# bash + cmd : Pass one command output into second command

Tags: bash, cmd, makefile

I'm trying to pass the output of one command into another without success.
I try to list all `.yaml` files in a directory into a one comma delimited string and pass the result into another command.

This is what I got so far:

I'm using this command:

`ls *.yaml -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','`

to list all files created as a comma separated which output something like:

```
api-pod.yaml,login-pod.yaml,mongo-pod.yaml,web-pod.yaml,
```

(Note that there is command in the end)

now, I need to pass this output into the `kubectl apply -f` command

```
kubectl apply -f (the output)
```

I've tried so far:

- kubectl apply -f $(ls *.yaml -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ',')
- kubectl apply -f `ls *.yaml -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','`
- for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`ls *.yaml -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','`) do kubectl apply -f %A

but none of them worked for me. I've tried both from `cmd` & bash (`MINGW64` on windows)

A solution that will work in both Linux (bash) & Windows (cmd) would be great, but if none exist I will get along with Linux based solution.

Thanks!

**Edit**: (maybe) important to note that I run the command from Makefile

```
kompose:
    # this will generate all the .yaml files
    kompose convert
    # this doesn't work for me
    kubectl apply -f "$(ls *.yaml -p | tr '\n' ',')"
    # this doesn't work for me either
    kubectl apply -f "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.yaml" -type f -printf "%f,")"
```

and running it using `make kompose`

**Another Edit:**

Running @RicoChen solution(s) works for me directly within MINGW, but doesn't works from the Makefile (if anyone has an idea why it would be appreciated)

I am sure all the solution you guys mentioned are working perfectly in real linux bash. this is the only solution that worked inside MINGW too.

**Another Edit:** 
Tried all your solutions from CygWin. no one works. either from Makefile or directly in CygWin.

**(Hopefully) last edit:**
This is the command that worked for me directly in MINGW: `kubectl apply -f $(ls -m *.yaml | tr -d ' ')` ( @RicoChen 's solution )
When I try to run it from Makefile: (using `make kompose` in MINGW)

```
.PHONY: kompose
kompose:
    kompose convert
    kubectl apply -f $(ls -m *.yaml | tr -d ' ')
```

It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Why do you need the `grep -v /`? Do you expect to have directories with names ending in `.yaml`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good question! no. I don't expect. so I guess `ls *.yaml -p | tr '\n' ','` is enough. thank you!

Comment: "From a makefile" changes things **a lot**; you should be tagging this as a make question (and actually, since you already got several answers, it's probably inappropriate to add that major a detail this late; better to accept any answer that works correctly outside a makefile, and then ask a new question that's explicitly about the makefile case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy doesn't change much. running directly this command: `kubectl apply -f "$(ls *.yaml -p | tr '\n' ',')"` from MINGW results in error: `error: the path "" does not exist`. running: `kubectl apply -f "$(ls *.yaml -p | tr '\n' ',')"` results in the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to use `find` command with `-exec` option:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.yaml" -exec kubectl apply -f {} \;
```

What this does is find all `*.yaml` files under current directory (recursively) and for each file found, run the command

```
kubectl apply -f file_found.yaml
```

[**EDIT**] If you do want to run kubectl apply once by appending multiple .yaml files, as indicated in your question, you can do

```
kubectl apply -f $(ls -m *.yaml | tr -d ' ')
```

Comment: can I pass all the files with comma delimitar to `kubectl apply` in one pass?

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for, but if kubectl doesn't actually expect to see a comma-separated list of names, perhaps it's what they need.

Comment: If you look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#apply, the right way to use the apply command is to either run on each file separately or use '-f filename1.yaml -f filename2.yaml ...', that is, '-f' is required for each filename.

Comment: @RicoChen, ...thank you for doing the research there; I've amended a mechanism to my answer showing how to generate an extra `-f` for each argument.

Comment: @RicoChen looking at this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/
they support also comma delimited string: 
`kubectl apply -f frontend-service.yaml,redis-master-service.yaml,redis-slave-service.yaml,frontend-deployment.yaml,redis-master-deployment.yaml,redis-slave-deployment.yaml`

Comment: ok @ET-CS I've updated my answer to accommodate the usage you mentioned. Basically -m option in the ls command would provide comma delimited outputs and the td command removes the extra space in the delimiter.

Comment: @RicoChen Thank you!! you solutions seems to work for me directly from MINGW. doesn't work from `cmd` (but I haven't expected anything from cmd). running it from Makefile in MINGW results in `error: must specify one of -f and -k`. if you have any idea why it doesn't work from Makefile, that would be awesome :) thanks again!

Comment: @RicoChen Sure! thanks! I've updated the question with this portion

Comment: @ET-CS, just to make sure, does any of the yaml file's name have any special characters such as space?

Comment: @RicoChen no. none of them have special characters.

Comment: @ET-CS are you sure the error is the direct result of the kubectl apply command inside your make file? Asking because 1) the apply command works in your MINGW env 2) Is it possible that the error is caused by other kubectl commands, if any, in your make file?

Comment: @RicoChen yes. this error as a result of the `kubectl apply -f $(ls -m *.yaml | tr -d ' ')` line

Answer (score 0):

#### Exactly What You Asked For

A shell function to do this might look like:

```
apply_files() {
  local IFS=,
  kubectl apply -f "$*,"
}
```

thereafter:

```
apply_files *.yaml
```

This works because `$*` combines all items in the current argument list with the first character of `$IFS`, which we're defining as a comma in our function.

---

#### Correct Kubectl Usage

```
apply_files() ){
  local -a args=( )
  for arg; do
    args+=( -f "$arg" )
  done
  kubectl apply "${args[@]}"
}

apply_files *.yaml
```

Comment: Can I create function inside Makefile (as I am running it from make - adding example in the question)

Comment: It's possible, but a lot harder, and probably not worth the effort here.

Comment: tried putting your scripts inside `.sh` files and running it from MINGW (`./gen.sh`)
the first script resulted in the same error as from Make: `error: the path "" does not exist`. the second script resulted in other error: `./gen.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./gen.sh: line 1: `apply_files() ){'
`

Comment: "Syntax error near unexpected token" means you're running this code with `sh`, not `bash`. That's not a huge surprise, since `sh` is the shell make uses by default. When putting it in a script, start the script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and don't ever start it with `sh scriptname` -- if you *must* start it that way, use `bash scriptname`.

Comment: @ET-CS, `the path "" does not exist` sounds like the problem is the trailing comma. I put that there because your question showed it as part of the command you claimed you wanted. Change it from `"$*,"` to `"$*"`, and the output will be `foo,bar,baz` instead of `foo,bar,baz,`; without that final comma, `kubectl` won't be trying to read a file with an empty name.